# Slack chatPostMessage fails

Tags: errbot

I'm trying to send a message from a Plugin by calling directly to the bot

`self._bot.sc.api_call('chat.postMessage', data={
    'channel': "#general",
    'text': "test msg",
    'unfurl_media': 'true',
    'as_user': 'true',
     })`

Always returns with:
   `{'ok': False, 'error': 'channel_not_found'}`

Answer (score 0):

`#general` is your channel name, not your channel Id, so you should use channel Id, you can find your channel id [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage/test)

Comment: please make user you have joined the channel, or you have permission

Comment: I'm in the channel

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

    `self._bot.sc.api_call(
        'chat.postMessage',
         channel="#general",
         text="My message text here",
         unfurl_media='true',
         as_user='true',
       )`